# Erlang scope of failure

Tags: erlang

If I have two Erlang modules: A and B, unlinked.

In A:

```
 start() -> register(A, spawn_link(A,init,[])).

 init() -> loop().

 loop() ->
    receive
        {request, call_B} -> B:method(),
        loop()
    end.

 call_method() -> A !  {request, call_B}.
```

In B:

```
 start() -> register(B, spawn_link(B,init,[])).

 init() -> loop().

 loop() ->
  receive
   {request, do} -> do_something...,
   loop()
  end.

 method() -> B ! {request, do}.
```

Then in shell:

```
 A:start(),
 B:start(),
 A:call_method().
```

Now, there is an exception in do_something and so B dies. Will A also die in this case?

I have tried to start A in the shell and then kill A. And the shell is indeed restarted. Can I conclude that the answer to the above question is yes based on this behaviour?

Comment: Do you mean you have two Erlang processes, rather than two modules?

Comment: I think you can say so. Each module has a start_link().

Comment: @SteveVinoski I have edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: It's still confusing, though. `B:method()` calls the `method/0` function in module `B`, but that by itself has nothing to do with process B unless `B:method/0` sends a message to process B that then leads to its death.

Comment: The code is not really illustrative of the question, but I tried to answer what I think you're asking.

Comment: Do you mean in the shell, specifically?

Comment: @zxq9 not the shell. I am thinking if A will die because B dies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you are confusing processes and modules, which is so common, I even [blogged about it](http://tkowal.wordpress.com/2014/09/09/erlang-otp-gen_server-boilerplate/). The example on my blog shows, that in one module, you can have code, that is run in two processes. And usually you have.

There is no such thing like 'linked modules'. Only *processes* can be linked.

So in your example. So in your example:

- you have a shell process
- you spawn process A, that uses loop from module `A` and is linked to shell
- you spawn process B, that uses loop from module `B` and is also linked to shell
- you send message to process `A` to call `B:method`

and now is the tricky part: if `method` is something like this:

```
method() ->
    1 / 0.
```

it is still called in process A and process A dies.
It is linked to shell, so shell dies and shell is linked to B, so B dies. (I assume you are not trapping exists).

But usually `method` is something like this:

```
method() ->
    B ! do_something.
```

And then, it will B, that crashes, which will carsh the shell, which will crash A. You can break the chain, by setting `trap_exit` flag on one of the processes. For example on the shell process. Try this in your shell:

```
process_flag(trap_exit, true). % don't crash shell, when linked process dies
spawn_link(fun() -> 1/0 end).  % spawn_link process, that dies
flush().                       % shell did not die - it got message, that you can view with flush/0
```

Comment: Brilliant explanation! I think you are right that I am confused with process and module...So, does the last line imply that A won;t die?

Comment: As zxq9 wrote. Links are bi-directional, so if B dies, then shell dies and A will also die. It is a chain reaction. But if at least one process is trapping exits. It will get a message instead of dying and it will break the chain.

Comment: I updated the answer to show, how to "break the links chain". It illustrates how trapping exits work in shell.

Answer (score 1):

Links are two-way. When you create a link between A and B, and a link between A and C, they are all within the same "scope of failure". The *same* exit message does not propagate across all the links, but each link is a channel of 'EXIT' message propagation. If B crashes it sends an exit to A, so it crashes, and when it crashes it sends an exit to C. This sort of chaining can be arbitrarily long or wide

A process that is trapping exits interrupts this propagation and treats any 'EXIT' message it receives as just a message, not as an indication it should also crash.

You can create any sort of graph shape you want with links (understanding they are *bidirectional*, of course -- to make a cyclic graph you would need monitors, which are one-way), but most of the time Erlang programs are designed in trees where exit trapping is only done near the root of the tree by supervisors.

Just for fun, here is an illustration where a crash propagates through the shell:

```
1> register(foo, spawn_link(fun() -> receive M -> io:format("~p~n", [M]) end end)).
true
2> register(bar, spawn_link(fun() -> receive M -> io:format("~p~n", [M]) end end)). 
true
3> exit(whereis(bar), kill).
** exception exit: killed
4> foo ! hey.
** exception error: bad argument
     in operator  !/2
        called as foo ! hey
```

First we spawn two processes, registered as 'foo' and 'bar', which are both linked to the shell. All they do is sit and wait to repeat some message. Before sending any message to them, we brutally murder 'bar'. 'bar's exit message is sent to the shell, so the shell dies after line 3 and is restarted by its supervisor (so we get the prompt back at line 4). Is 'foo' still alive? We try sending a message to it only to find that... it no longer exists! When the shell crashed it sent an exit message to all of its linked processes, and 'foo' was one of them (the shell supervisor is another). 'foo' wasn't trapping exits, so it died, but the shell's supervisor was trapping exits so received a message `{'EXIT', Proc, Reason}` (the shell's supervisor knew it was the shell and that it needed to be restarted, and did so).